# Do you need to specify an effect to counteract with Remove Disease or similar?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, disease

[Remove Disease](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=251) specifies

> You attempt to [counteract](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=371) one disease afflicting the target.

Do you need to pick a specific instance of disease to remove? Or is it random/determined by GM/something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't need to

*Remove disease* is a very brief spell, but by its **Targets** entry of "1 creature" it can be cast on any particular creature (regardless of the presence of a disease/diseases). If the creature is afflicted with a disease, the spell will attempt to counteract it.

As to what should happen when the spell is cast upon a creature with multiple diseases, that'd be up to GM discretion. It seems reasonable that the caster should be able to select a particular disease if they knew of it (or even just a particular symptom), otherwise if the spell treats their common cold instead of the magical super plague it seems like a weird outcome. But a GM might decide it's random or perhaps something like the highest-level disease afflicting the creature.